# How to connect Client IP's to Different Directories

Tags: java, sockets, directory, hashmap, file-sharing

I am creating a file sharing program, though this one only works locally, I am trying to connect two different clients to two different directories ( both of these directories are on the same computer) and show the files connected to different ports ( and possible IP's if that is possible).

I have some code to place the filenames and the IP's + port in a hashmap key and value respectively. But currently they are both connected to the same ip and port.

When I open two different clients they have two different ports.( I can see that in the server GUI)

```
    case ServerConstants.CLIENT_PUBLISHES:
                int switchC = 1;
                if(switchC == 1){
                File client1Folder = new File(
                        "C:\\###### #####\\##### #######\\### ######\\client1");
                File[] allFilesClient1 = client1Folder.listFiles();

                for (File fileName : allFilesClient1) {

                    Index.fileDir.put(fileName.getName(),
                            (remoteClient.getInetAddress().toString() + " " + remoteClient.getPort()));

                    }
                    switchC++;
                }
                if(switchC == 2){
                File client2Folder = new File(
                        "C:\\###### #####\\##### #######\\### ######\\client2");
                File[] allFilesClient2 = client2Folder.listFiles();

                for (File fileName1 : allFilesClient2) {

                    Index.fileDir.put(fileName1.getName(),
                            (remoteClient.getInetAddress().toString() + " " + remoteClient.getPort()));
                }
                System.out.print(" CPub Method Ended \n");

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : Index.fileDir
                        .entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(mapEntry.getKey() + " || "
                            + mapEntry.getValue());
                }
                break;
                }
```

Comment: Let me get this right, you have many clients with different ip, and you want each one to see some "files/directories" depending on their ip?

Comment: Almost, Many clients, different IP **ports** and want each port to connect to different directory depending on there port, though I don't think have different IP's as it is local.

Comment: Probably you do not need `if(switchC == 1)` as it will always be true in your `case` statements.

Comment: There is a possibility that the two different clients have same file name which you are actually using as key. In that case later entry can overwrite the former.

Comment: Using `fileName` as key is not a good idea as you want a key to be unique.

Comment: @akhil_mittal always true? ido have a switchC++; in there, there are current six documents called doc  1 - doc6, why do I want filename to unique or do you mean port should be unique